# Как получить подключение к БД в codeignther

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет. Если использовать

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'denis', '1q2w3e4r5t6y7u8i9o0p', 'build');
$regs = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *  FROM tm_subcategory WHERE id_category=$id_category");
```

То мы получаем $link где хранится подключение. А как получить это подключение в codeignther. Ведь все параметры к подключению храняться в файле database.php

Comment: зачем если там наверняка уже доступна какая-нибудь переменная `$db` для работы с БД? даже еще проще ... там уже в моделях можно писать `$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");`  надо просто открыть документацию и почитать  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/examples.html

Comment: [Подключение к базе](http://codeigniter3.info/guide/database/connecting)